# Does anybody played Korg Kross 88, are keys heavy and weighted there like on acoustic pianos?

Tags: digital-piano

Does anybody played Korg Kross 88, are keys heavy and weighted there like on acoustic pianos and on expensive digital pianos? Is it good enough for playing Chopin an Liszt etudes (and recording them for competitions and radio)?

Answer (score 1):

Question one can be answered from manufacturer website: Natural Weighted Hammer Action

Question two: I doubt it, besides a [German test](https://www.bonedo.de/artikel/einzelansicht/korg-kross-88-test.html) summarizing the disadvantages as "sound quality not always fully convincing" (so you need something else for the sound) and "weighted keys somewhat spongy" I simply doubt that one gets a stage piano (if that form factor is important to you) satisfying at least semi-professional ambitions in the 1000$ range. What you require is pure mechanics and that still is connected with considerable costs .

Comment: any personal preference and you wish to advise?

Comment: @VassiaAlk: my son plays this kind of music, did a lot of research and tried instruments extensively;  he is now very happy with his Kawai MP-11 (about 2800$). The Kawai CA digital pianos share the same key mechanics and are similar priced.